Reflection phase change in laser cavity using the Transfer Matrix Method
Say I have an optical system consisting of two partial-reflection mirrors with free space in between them. I am using the Transfer Matrix Method (TMM) to describe this system.

Through some mathematics, assuming normalised inputs $B=1$ and $C=0$, I have equations for the transmission amplitudes
$ D = \frac{t^2}{e^{-ikL}-r^2e^{ikL}}$,
$A = \frac{r(e^{-ikL} +e^{ikL}(t^2-r^2)}{e^{-ikL}-r^2e^{ikL}}$.
where $t$ and $r$ are the mirrors' transmission and reflection coefficients, and $L$ is the cavity length.
Now, the cavity length should not only represent the physical length ($L = \frac{n\lambda}{2}$), but should also account to some reflection phase shift based on the mirrors' equation. Is there a way where I can obtain an expression for this phase shift based on my transfer matrix?

You'll want to express $A$ as the product of an amplitude and a phase factor.  So, I would first start by writing $A$ in the form of $(G + i H)$.
The amplitude is $\sqrt{G^2 + H^2}$.
The phase factor can be written as $\exp{\left[i \arctan \left(\dfrac{H}{G}\right)\right]}$.

That should work. For further simplicity,  I wonder if one could use a part of the amplitude rather than the whole expression. I remember reading a paper where they used the denominator together with the argument of the reflection coefficient, however I'm afraid I do not recall their reasoning nor the reference.
